# how to get number exist or not in a string value in sql

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have string like this '1~5~14~62~53~26' in a sql column, actually these are values of a user selected list. Now i want to check if the given string contains specific value like '5' exist or not how can i achieve this in sql query?

Comment: RTFM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html and then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization to learn how to build your DB properly so that this problem would never have happened in the first place.

Comment: there are 1400+ cities in my cities table if user selects few cities how can i store selected values other than this above mentioned method?

Comment: By using a normalized design. look up 3rd normal form in the second link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ab06/1)

**MySQL 5.6.6 m9 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     cities varchar(20)
    );

INSERT INTO mytable
(cities)
VALUES
('5~1~23~45~9~8~71'),
('2~22~39~8~23~5'),
('2~22~39~8~5~9'),
('2~22~39~8~23');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT `cities` FROM `mytable` where `cities` REGEXP '^5~|~5$|~5~'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ab06/1/0)**:

```
|           CITIES |
|------------------|
| 5~1~23~45~9~8~71 |
|   2~22~39~8~23~5 |
|    2~22~39~8~5~9 |
```

More about [REGEXP and RLIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html)

Comment: You are welcome. Just to tighten the rule further, you may want to change the REGEXP to `'^5~|~5$|~5~|^5$'` to take care of a single value all by itself

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
SELECT * from MyTable where locate(concat('~','5','~'), concat('~',`MyColumn`,'~')) != 0;
```

It's horrible, and prone to error.

The real solution is to normalise your data, which in this case means put your user-selected list entries in a separate table, indexed by user id.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it in MySQL?**

Then use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `col_name` REGEXP '[5]';
```